# Php - How to remove number from a specific string?

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove a number only from a specific string. In particular:

```
$item = preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $item);
```

but in this way it replaces all numbers from all strings. I instead need to remove only number after string 'team'.

How can I do this?

```
team2567 = team;
season1617 = season1617;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make it like

```
$item = preg_replace('/team\d+/u', 'team', $item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Positive Lookbehind

```
$item = preg_replace('/(?<=team)\d+/u', '', $item);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $str = 'In My Cart : 11 12 items';
 preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
$item = preg_replace('/team\d+/u', 'team', $item);
```

or with capturing group

```
$item = preg_replace('/(team)\d+/u', '$1', $item);
```

or with positive lookbehind

```
$item = preg_replace('/(?<=team)\d+/u', '', $item);
```

Comment: Or `preg_replace('/(team)\d+/', '$1', $item)`